# Можно ли к проекту, созданному в FlashDevelop, добавить графический интерфейс?

Tags: flash

Допустим, что у меня есть проект, включающий несколько классов, написанный на ActionScript 3.0, могу ли я добавить к нему графический интерфейс, созданный в другой среде (желательно, бесплатной)?

Comment: Попробуйте редактор GIOTTO  - http://vectorian.com/giotto/


- полученную swf интегрируйте в свой проект с помощью тега [Embed]

вот пример - http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я находил где-то инструкцию, как добавить SWF с помощью инъекции в проект, но у меня просто нет таких пунктов в меню. Может, нужны какие-то плагины или дополнительные настройки?

Comment: - Да, там надо качать расширение и swftools ставить. http://technoargia.free.fr/swftools/

- инструкции по установке читайте в readme.txt

Comment: @ShockWave, а не подскажете, какое расширение нужно?

Comment: Нужно inkscape2swf

Там есть ссылка  - http://technoargia.free.fr/swftools/inkscape2swf.tgz

Инструкция по установке тут - http://technoargia.free.fr/swftools/readme.txt